# State changes from parent to children not reflected to TextField in React Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I pass a component (C) as props to a Child component (B) inside a Parent component (A). State of A is also passed to C and mapped to C's state. But when I update A's state and B's state accordingly, state of C does not update.

My code looks like this: (import statements are omitted)

```
const Parent = (props) => {
    .............(other state)
    const [info, setInfo] = React.useState(props.info);

    const handleDataChanged = (d) => { setInfo(d); }

    return (
        <div>
            ........(other stuffs)
            <MyModal
                ..........(other props)
                body={ <MyComp data={ info } updateData={ handleDataChanged } /> }
            />
        </div>
    );
}


const MyModal = (props) => {
    ..........(other state)
    const [content, setContent] = React.useState(props.body);

    React.useEffect(() => { setContent(props.body); }, [props]);

    return (
        <Modal ...>
            <div>{ content }</div>
        </Modal>
    );
}


const MyComp = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(props.data);

    React.useEffect(() => { setData(props.data); }, [props]);

    return (
        data && <TextField value={ data.name }
                           onChange={ e => {
                                      let d = data;
                                      d.name = e.target.value;
                                      props.updateData(d); }} />
    );
}
```

When I type something in the TextField, I see `Parent`'s `info` changed. The `useEffect` of `MyModal` is not fired. And `data` in `MyComp` is not updated.

Update: After more checking the above code and the solution below, the problem is still, but I see that `data` in `MyComp` does get changes from `Parent`, but the TextField does not reflect it.

Someone please show me how can I update `data` from `MyComp` and reflect it to `Parent`. Many thanks!

Comment: Do props change in Modal? What happens when you log Modal props?

Comment: `Modal`'s `props` are `open={ open }` and `onClose={ () => props.hanleClose() }` which are not changed as `Modal` is supposed to be opened. But `Modal`'s `useEffect` is not fired when I type in TextField, so its `content` is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem with my code is that: React Hook does not have an idea whether a specific property or element in a state object has changed or not. It only knows if the whole object has been changed.

For example: if you have an array of 3 elements or a Json object in your state. If one element in the array changes, or one property in the Json object changes, React Hook will identiy them unchanged.

Therefore to actually broadcast the change, you must deep clone your object to a copy, then set that copy back to your state. To do this, I use lodash to make a deep clone.

Ref: https://dev.to/karthick3018/common-mistake-done-while-using-react-hooks-1foj

So the code should be:

In MyComp:

```
onChange={e => { let d = _.cloneDeep(data); d.name = e.target.value; props.handleChange(d) }}
```

In Parent:

```
const handleChange = (data) => {
    let d = _.cloneDeep(data);
    setInfo(d);
}
```

Then pass the handleChange as delegate to MyComp as normal.

Comment: You should not be using React hooks to propagate changes to state through components. You should be using props directly. Changes in props are automatically propogated. That's why the framework is called React. Components 'react' to changes in state. If you keep copying the same state into every component your creating unecessary problems for yourself.

Comment: What specific element of state is not being updated? And is it being copied unnecessarily? If so remove the step where you copy props to state and use the prop directly.

Comment: Using props in place of state is an antipattern. The easy way is not always a good practice.

Comment: I agree but you are setting state from props, so that kind of defeats the point of what you are saying. You are duplicating state in multiple locations and I'm encouraging you to keep state to a single parent component. I don't understand if you have solved the problem or are still asking for help. You have completely changed the nature of this question by editing the title, making this very hard for other people to follow. Do you still have a problem or have you solved it?

Comment: If you have solved your problem,  can you please explain "Using props in place of state is an antipattern.", I would like to know more and I think it would be useful for other people following this in the future.

Comment: My suggestion to do the opposite comes mainly from the react docs on the matter https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: The document says the antipattern is child component updates its state while it is controlled by parent, so it switches from being controlled to uncontrolled. It’s obvious as anyone should see a clash a head of time between parent state (passing as props to its children) and the child’s own state as the changes come from different sources. But in my case, Parent still controls the state of MyComp, and what MyComp does is to call the delegate passed from its parent to update Parent state then map it again to children. In fact, there will be a warning in console if this antipattern occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, it looks like you are trying to recreate the children api https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren.

Much easier if you use props.children to compose your components instead of passing props up and down.

```
const MyModal = (props) => {
    ...(other state)
    return (
        <Modal>
            <div>{ props.children }</div>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

Then you can handle functionality directly in the parent without having to map props to state (which is strongly discouraged)...

```
const Parent = (props) => {
    ...(other state)
    const [info, setInfo] = React.useState(props.info);

    const handleDataChanged = d => setInfo(d);

    return (
        <div>
            ...(other stuffs)
            <MyModal {...props}>
             <MyComp data={ info } updateData={ handleDataChanged } /> 
           </MyModal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The upside of this approach is that there is much less overhead. rather than passing State A to C and mapping to C's state, you can just do everything from State A (the parent component). No mapping needed, you have one source of truth for state and its easier to think about and build on.

Alternatively, if you want to stick to your current approach then just remove `React.useEffect(() => { setContent(props.body); }, [props]);` in `MyModal` and map props directly like so

```
<Modal>
  <div>{ props.body }</div>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I change my code to use `props.children` but it's still the same. After further checking, I see that in both ways, `data` in `MyComp` does get new state from `Parent`, but the TextField does not show the value.

Comment: This is a slightly different issue. So if you are composing then the texfield value should be `value={ props.data.name }` Can you confirm that props.data.name is being passed into the MyComp component as expected. What happens when you log its value?

Comment: Again, in `MyComp` you should not be mapping props to state. You should be using props directly. Never maps props to state, lift state up in situations like this so that one component controls state, making everything easier to think about.

Comment: Ye I have removed all mapping and use `props` instead, but the value (although updated to props from Parent) does not show accordingly in TextField. This is so strange.

Comment: Please clarify. You are saying that `props.data.name` is logging as expected in `MyComp` but just not appearing in the `TextField` component? If this is the case I suggest you create a new question with your new code and this new problem and we can dissect the problem there. If you do make sure to explain what `TextField` is, a custom component or something from a library?

Comment: @JayNguyen please accept my answer if I have solved your problem. If not, please explain what the problem is.

Comment: It does not solve the problem, it just suggests another way to write the code.

Comment: But then the problem is not related to the question you asked. Please explain what the problem is now and let's fix it.

Comment: The problem does relate. Please see my answer below. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: Changing the title of your question to relate to a new problem is counterproductive to other people who are following this with a similar problem in the future.